# Is it possible to use external DLL inside of Metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am a new in developing Metro application. And I have a question regarding external DLL for Metro.

As I understand project which implemented DLL(extension) should be include in solution for Metro application. And I should specify dependency into Package.appxmanifest. Only after that action I can use this extension in my Metro application.

But what about external DLL(extension)? 
How to use DLL installed on system (something like load library for Desktop)?
Could somebody clarify this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows Store App is sand boxed and can't access any system DLLs, or DLLs other than the ones provided in your project.

Also DLLs referenced by your project need to be WinRT DLLs built specially for WinRT.

Comment: Thanks. And so it means that we cannot use WinRT DLLs sided vendors. If I wanted to use sided DLLS, I should include it in my project. I should have source code, VS solution for this DLLs etc. Yes? How to handle this situation?

Comment: You can include a reference to a WinRT dll in your project. You don't need the source code.

Comment: But if I understand correctly this dll should be placed in the same folder with solution and should be distributed with my solution. Right?

Comment: Yes, try it and see how you get on.

Comment: How to handle situation if I would like to use DLLs installed on system? Is there a way to do this? Or it is impossible?

Comment: If you really want to use installed DLLs then make a desktop app.